# How to upload maximum data with java script/node in multiple threads to measure achievable throughput

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, browser, promise

**Goal - Upload Garbage data to server as much as we can within stipulated time to measure maximum throughput in multiple threads.**

```
        function makeUploadRequest(i, data) {
    
        if (dataUpload != null) {
            numULRunnnigThread++;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 0) {}
                if (this.readyState == 1) {
                    if (!hasValue(MAX_END_TIME)) {
                        MAX_END_TIME = ((new Date()).getTime() + 20000);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            runUpload = false;
    
                        }, (20000));
    
                    }
                }
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    
                    numULRunnnigThread--;
                    sendArrayBuffer(5 - numRunnnigThread, new ArrayBuffer(25000000));
    
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.open('POST', UPLOAD_URL, true);
        xhr.send(data);
    }
    
       
        
        function sendArrayBuffer(offset, dataToSent) {
            for (var i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
                makeUploadRequest(i, dataToSent);
            }
        }

 sendArrayBuffer(4, new ArrayBuffer(25000000));
```

> I could upload but unable to get maximum throughout which is coming
> in network bandwidth.

Comment: Java has no relationship to javascript. Please remove the java tag. You should know the language that you're asking about.

Comment: bro i have written my server rest api in java, thats why i mentioned.